# How to return the payload of redux saga watcher

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

Example code

```js
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

interface Props {
  data: string;
}
export interface WatcherResult extends AnyAction {
  payload: PROPS
}

type TacPopulate = () => WatcherResult;
const acPopulate: TacPopulate = () => ({
  type: 'POPULATE',
  payload: {}
});


function* sagaWorker(
  action: WatcherResult
): Generator<StrictEffect, WatcherResult, Props> {
  return = {
    data: 'hello world'
  });
}

function* sagaWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery('POPULATE', sagaWorker);
}

// trigger
dispatch({
  type: 'POPULATE'
});
```

The method correctly dispatches but the reducer does not receive the new payload.
It seems I always have to do an additional 'yield put' like this, which seems superfluous code and bloat which I have to receive by separate reducer method.

```
function* sagaWorker(
  action: WatcherResult
): Generator<StrictEffect, WatcherResult, Props> {
  yield put({
    type: 'YET_ANOTHER_ACTIONTYPE',
    payload: {
      data: 'hello world'
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are asking is to change the existing action.  That's not how redux-saga works.  In your example, your reducer will receive two actions:

```
{type: "POPULATE"}
```

```
{type: "YET_ANOTHER_ACTIONTYPE", payload: {data: "hello world"}}
```

When the saga "takes" an action, that action still goes through to the store.

---

If you want to stop an action and replace it then you need custom middleware.  Here we look for "POPULATE" actions with an empty `payload` and replace it with one with data.

```
import { Middleware } from "redux";

export const replaceAction: Middleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === "POPULATE" && !action.payload) {
    console.log("caught action");
    const data = "hello world";
    const replacedAction = {
      ...action,
      payload: { data }
    };
    return next(replacedAction);
  } else return next(action);
};
```

---

> which I have to receive by separate reducer method.

Maybe, not always.  Does your reducer need to do anything at all when you call `{type: "POPULATE"}` with no data?  Sometimes the "trigger action" is used to set some sort of state like `isLoading: true` in the reducer.  Other times you can skip over it entirely.

---

> which seems superfluous code and bloat

Using thunks with [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) is a lot easier to implement if you aren't committed to saga.

---

As far as your Typescript types are concerned, the action created by `acPopulate` is invalid because the `payload` is empty (maybe there was something here in your actual code).  You would need to change this up so that there is a difference between a populate request, which has no payload, and a populate success which contains the data.

```
const requestPopulate = () => ({
  type: "POPULATE_REQUEST"
});

const populateWithData = (data: string) => ({
  type: "POPULATE_SUCCESS",
  payload: {
    data
  }
});

function* sagaWorker(action: AnyAction) {
  yield put(populateWithData("hello world"));
}

function* sagaWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery("POPULATE_REQUEST", sagaWorker);
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is I must have both a watcher action type and the result change action type? Of which only one needs to be in the reducer.